# postgres query where values contain backslash

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm in the process of migrating a db from MySql to PostgreSql

I have one last thing outstanding: In the table `steps` there is a column `overlay_custom_css`.

Example of data in customer_overlay_css:
`left:957px;\r\ntop:594px;\r\nwidth:68px;\r\nheight:30px;`

I need to remove the `\r\n` from this data. As I understand it, the \ is a special char so must be escaped by another \

source:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Here's what I have so far:

```
UPDATE
  steps
SET
  overlay_custom_css = REPLACE(overlay_custom_css,'\\r\\n','')
WHERE
  overlay_custom_css LIKE '%\\r\\n%';
```

After I run this it says it affected 200+ rows, but looking at my data it made no difference.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_replace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html).

```
select regexp_replace(overlay_custom_css,'\\r\\n','','g')
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked `UPDATE steps SET overlay_custom_css = regexp_replace(overlay_custom_css,'\\r\\n','','g')`

Answer (score 1):

To use the [*C-style escapes*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html) you need to use `E''`

> PostgreSQL also accepts "escape" string constants, which are an extension to the SQL standard. An escape string constant is specified by writing the letter E (upper or lower case) just before the opening single quote, e.g., E'foo'. (When continuing an escape string constant across lines, write E only before the first opening quote.) Within an escape string, a backslash character () begins a C-like backslash escape sequence, in which the combination of backslash and following character(s) represent a special byte value, as shown in Table 4-1.

so it looks like this,

```
SELECT x, replace(x, E'\r\n', '')
FROM ( VALUES
  (E'foo\r\nbar')
) AS t(x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, This didn't work though, I suspect due to the like clause to work `E'%\r\n%'` but in anycase, problem solved. Ty

Answer (score 0):

If using Laravel, use quad-escapes:

```
// querying for 'Foo\Bar'...
Model::where('foo', 'like', 'Foo\\\\Bar')->get()
```